# Column Alias in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have table with following table schema :

[image]

I have created a method that returns the list of value on query execution.

```
    protected List findAllWithGroupClause(Class clazz) {

    List objects = null;
    try {
        startOperation();
        String SQL_QUERY = "SELECT COUNT(serviceName) AS RunningInstances ,serviceName,SUM(numberofthread) as workerThread "
                + "FROM servicemanagerdetails WHERE servicemanagerstatus=:status GROUP BY serviceName";
        Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
        query.setString("status", "Running");
        objects = query.list();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        handleException(e);
    } finally {
        HibernateFactory.close(session);
    }
    return objects;
}
```

and for that declared ServiceManagerDetails.hbm.xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.arosys.hibernatedatamanager.ServiceManagerDetails" table="servicemanagerdetails">
    <id column="servicedetailsid" name="servicedetailsID" type="integer">
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property column="serviceID" name="servicemanagerID" type="string"/>
    <property column="servicemode" name="servicemode" type="string"/>
    <property column="servicetype" name="servicetype" type="string"/>
    <property column="servicemanagerstatus" name="servicemanagerstatus" type="string"/>
    <property column="controlqueue" name="controlQueue" type="string"/>
    <property column="controlexchange" name="contolExchange" type="string"/>
    <property column="controlroutingkey" name="controlRoutingkey" type="string"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

i have created column alias for that  it is necessary to write setter and getter method as well as define mapping?please explain how can retrieve value from list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a select statement for selecting aggregate functions COUNT, SUM etc. In this case the hibernate `Query.list()` returns a list of arrays of objects.

If you want to get the SUM of the fourth row, you do

```
Object obj4[] = objects.get(3);
long sum4 = ((Number)obj4[2]).longValue();
```

and for the serviceName of the third row you do

```
Object obj3[] = objects.get(2);
String name2 = (String)obj4[2];
```

(both examples for explaining; your code will look more variable).

You do not need to write getters and setters, you even can't do that. You can't use the column aliases outside the select string.